# Adjusting position of jQuery Facebox before triggering

Tags: jquery, facebox

I wish to adjust the height of my dialog box.

I could do it this way, but there is an weird abrupt shift, esp if the pc is slow.

```
$.facebox($("#step1Facebox").html());
$("#facebox").css("top","175px");
```

Is there a way of doing it such the position is pre-adjusted before showing up?

Comment: Have you tried setting your style before $.facebox() is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a default CSS style for #facebox

```
#facebox {
    display:none;
}
```

Then fade in the box...

```
$.facebox($("#step1Facebox").html());
$("#facebox").css("top","175px").fadeIn();
```

**Or**, try this - but it depends whether facebox returns itself in the constructor:

```
$.facebox($("#step1Facebox").html()).hide();
$("#facebox").css("top","175px").fadeIn();
```

Comment: It really worked well, thanks Shane Garelja